# NodeJs Twig ForEach not working

Tags: node.js, foreach, twig

I'm building a small application as part of a school project using NodeJS and Twig.

I don't have any trouble to print data, except for my foreach statement.

My view :

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>My sessions</h1>
    {% for session in Sessions %}
    <div class="container">
        <h3>
            {{ link(session.sessionStart,"/sessions/"+session.id) }}
        </h3>
        <p>Latitude : {{ session.latitude }}</p>
        <p>Longitude : {{ session.longitude }}</p>
        <p>Number of observations : {{ session.observations.length }}</p>
        <p>Status : {{ session.status }}</p>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <p>{{ Message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm sure the data is present in `Sessions`. When I try to output id of the first element, like so:

```
{{ Sessions[0].id }}
```

then the `id` is printed. When Sessions is empty, the `{{ Message }}` is printed.

Writing only `{{ "Hello World" }}` in the foreach does not produces any output either.

Otherwise, I end up with a page containing only the title.

EDIT:

When I use the console on Sessions, I get this :

> console.log(Sessions) ‌
>   undefined
>      [ NataSession {
>       id: 901,
>       latitude: 50.85,
>       longitude: 4.35,
>       observations: [],
>       sessionEnd: 'Dec 8, 2017 5:15:00 PM',
>       sessionStart: 'Dec 8, 2017 5:06:00 PM',
>       status: 'Refused',
>       userId: 1 } ]

And I build it this way :

```
client.get(this.restBaseUrl+"sessions/user/"+user.id,function(data,response){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(response);
            var Sessions = [];
            var i=0;
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                Sessions.push(new NataSession());
                Sessions[i].id          = data[i].id          ;
                Sessions[i].latitude    = data[i].latitude    ;
                Sessions[i].longitude   = data[i].longitude   ;
                Sessions[i].observations= data[i].observations;
                Sessions[i].sessionEnd  = data[i].sessionEnd  ;
                Sessions[i].sessionStart= data[i].sessionStart;
                Sessions[i].status      = data[i].status      ;
                Sessions[i].userId      = data[i].userId      ;
            }
            var message = "";
            if(data.length == 0){
                message = "You don't have any sessions yet."
            }
            res.render('sessions', { title: 'Natagora - Sessions',Sessions:Sessions,Message:message});
```

Comment: What if you `dump` Sessions? Is it iterable?

Comment: I added this in the question. I followed instructions found here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html to use the for helper and here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp for the creation of the array. Sorry for my mistakes, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not the for in itself, but rather the `{{ link(session.sessionStart,"/sessions/"+session.id) }}`

Here is a working code :

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>My sessions</h1>
    {% for session in Sessions %}
    <div class="container" style="margin: 30px;padding:15px; background-color: gainsboro">
        <h3>
            <a href="{{ session.link }}">{{ session.sessionStart }}</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Latitude : {{ session.latitude }}</p>
        <p>Longitude : {{ session.longitude }}</p>
        <p>Number of observations : {{ session.observations.length }}</p>
        <p>Status : {{ session.status }}</p>
        <button>Share on Facebook</button>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <p>{{ Message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

`link` is a property I added and is generated in the back-end. It is a relative url to the session page.